# Postman Test: accept only allowed attributes in JSON schema

Tags: json, postman, web-api-testing

we have a question regarding testing with Postman. We have an API that delivers a response in JSON. This response contains sub-selection of the attributes. In the requests we define the attributes which should be in the response body and there shall be only this attributes. We couldn't find out how to test with Postman, that no additional attributes are returned in the response body.

Example:
Request Body - `{"housenumber": "24","room": ["roomtype", "wallcolor"] }`

The response body should look like this -

```
{
  "roomtype": "kitchen",
  "wallcolor": "white"
}
```

We want to test that "roomtype" and "wallcolor" are contained in the response body, but no other attributes. In the Database we have another attribute called "flooring" which should not appear in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities, one you can test in postman that the flooring field is not returned, but that would get annoying over a large code base.  The other is to use the [Postman Schema Validation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/design-and-develop-apis/validating-elements-against-schema/) feature and include a JSON schema.